# Passing & Adding two numbers using Parse Cloud code?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Ive got my Parse SDK set up, and the "Hello World!" function runs fine. Im trying to now send two int's (`i1` & `i2`) and return the sum. What I need to know is:

1) How to send variables

2) How to receive them. As changing the `HashMap` from `HashMap<String,Object>` to `HashMap<Integer,Object>` gives an error

**ParseCloud function (js)**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("add", function(request,response)
{
var intA = 1;
var intB = 2;
var intC = intA + intB;

//var s = "Hello Add!";
//response.success(s);
response.success(intC);
});
```

**Android method, doAddition()**

```
    s1 = et1.getText().toString();
    s2 = et2.getText().toString();

    i1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
    i2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);

    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("add",  new HashMap<Integer, Object>(), new FunctionCallback<Integer>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void done(Integer sum, ParseException e) 
        {
            s3 = sum.toString();
            et3.setText(s3);
        }
    });
```

The above Android-method gives an error:

```
 The method callFunctionInBackground(String, Map<String,?>,
 FunctionCallback<T>) in the type ParseCloud is not applicable for the
 arguments (String, HashMap<Integer,Object>, new
 FunctionCallback<Integer>(){})
```

Answer (score 0):

set your args correctly before the call to your Cloudfunction ( as proper javascript parms ) then get them in the cloud funct...

```
  var mathArg1 = request.params.arg1;
  var mathArg2 = request.params.arg2;
```

create a result field in JS...

```
  var mathResult = mathArg1 + mathArg2;
```

return the result to client as JSON  ( get used to this in cloud interfaces! )

```
success: function(user) {
    response.success(mathResult.toJSON());
},
```